# Motif GUI will only run if launched from terminal

Tags: linux, motif

I have an image processing app that uses a Motif (legacy GUI) front end.
It runs beautifully when launched from the terminal, but when launched from a desktop icon the system hangs for several seconds then nothing else happens. I build the GUI under a shell returned by XtVaOpenApplication(). When the icon is classed as a 'terminal application' the Motif GUI opens and runs normally but with an unneeded and unwanted terminal behind it.

Everything runs fine. It simply will not launch except from a terminal.

Comment: And what is your question? :) Could you show some code?

Comment: It's likely to do with the environment variables the terminal sets - or the terminal capabilities it provides. Get the error messages - perhaps by creating another icon which launches the app and logs stderr.

Comment: There are no error messages when launched from a terminal. It runs fine with no errors. And when it does not run when launched by a desktop icon, there is no terminal to display any messages sent to stdout. I suspect the application is never even being launched. The O/S is intercepting the launch somehow, going into some sort of search/wait state, then timing out. It is not a path issue; the same icon launches it if classified as a 'terminal application'.

Comment: @imagtek:
    1. If you run `ps -efl | grep ...`, what is the output in each case?
    2. Can you launch your application from `gdb`?